# vim python omnifunc not working some modules

Tags: pandas, vim

I started gVim lately in offline window pc.

Specification is below...

gVim - 9.1.0211 -64bit
python - windows embedded 3.11.8 (pandas 2.2.1) - 64bit
vimrc - filetype plugin indent on &_
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete

After typing "import pandas as pd pd.", I pressed `<C-x><C-o>` then it shows "pattern not matched" So I tested in vim `:echo has("python3")` then it returns `1`, and `:python3 import pandas` then it says `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations`.

In terminal, pandas is normally imported (python3 >> import pandas as pd >> ...)

Import numpy and omnifunc works well, modules related to pandas doesn't work. I installed vc_redist.64x but not solved.

Has anyone this problem like this? I need some help, Thanks.

since my pc is local (no internet connection) and remote environment,
so I don't have any verbose. sorry.

1. Check c:\windows\system32 and found msvcp140.dll and concrt140.dll
2. Install jedi-vim and failed load module(pandas) but after quit the error message autocompleting works partially and the error occurs again and again
3. Try Neovim (installed pynvim) and omnifunc works

Comment: Both the `+python3` feature and the `:python3` command are related to Vim's own Python interface. For Python development (let alone code completion) you don't need them.